# The fractional order derivative approach above

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, fractional-calculus

We recall the Riemann-Liouville left sided fractional $s$-order derivative is defined as, in interval $(0,1)$, where $0<s<1$,
$$
D^s_{[0,x]}f(x):=\frac{1}{\Gamma(1-s)}\frac d{dx}\int_0^x \frac{f(y)}{(x-y)^s}dy\tag 1
$$
for $x\in(0,1)$, where $\Gamma$ denotes the Gamma function.

It is clear that for $s=0$, $(1)$ reduces to $f(x)$. I am wondering what if $s=1$? should it give $f'(x)$? I suppose so, at least from the numerical point of view. But I found it hard to prove analyliticly... More precisely, what would $(1)$ become if we send $s\nearrow 1$? converge to $f'(x)$? If yes, in what capacity?

To be precise. For a function $f\in C_c^\infty(0,1)$, do we have 
$$
\lim_{s\nearrow 1} \int_0^1|D^s_{[0,x]}f(x)-f'(x)|dx =0?
$$

Any helps?

Comment: :D Thanks for taking part in the `fractional-calculus` tag, it hasn't gotten much attention lately.

Comment: What do you mean by "capacity"?  And the answer is yes, it approaches $f'(x)$.

Comment: @SimpleArt I mean, in what sense? a.e.? in $L^1$? etc... Could you provide some reference?

Comment: Haha, this is slightly amusing to me that I know of fractional derivatives, yet I don't know what $L^1$ means.  I presume it is a space, but I haven't studied real analysis much

Comment: If you've used multivariate chain rule before, let $u,v$ be functions of $x$ and differentiate the following:$$\frac d{dx}\int_0^u\frac{f(y)}{(v-y)^s}dy$$

Comment: I think that for $D_{[0,x]}^sf(x)$ to exist, there are usually more requirements on $f$ then just being $C^\infty$.  Not sure where I read that though.

Comment: @SimpleArt I think the boundary value of $f$ does matter, and this is why I am using $C_c^\infty$ instead of $C^\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it doesn't exist for $s=1$.  Indeed, this is why we have $0<s<1$.  You will notice that we have will have $\Gamma(0)$.  Indeed, $\Gamma(0)$ doesn't exist, and as $s\to1$, $\frac1{\Gamma(1-s)}\to0$.  Just the same, you will notice that if $f(x)\ne0$, then $\int_0^x\frac{f(y)}{(x-y)^s}dy\to\pm\infty$.  Thus we result with the following indeterminate form:

$$\frac1{\Gamma(1-s)}\frac d{dx}\int_0^x\frac{f(y)}{(x-y)^s}dy\stackrel{s\to1}=0\times\infty$$

which is quite unfortunate.  However, it is noticeable that if we were to evaluate the limit, we'd end up with the following:

$$\lim_{s\to1^-}\frac1{\Gamma(1-s)}\frac d{dx}\int_0^x\frac{f(y)}{(x-y)^s}dy=f'(x)$$

just as you would expect.

Now, if $u,v$ were functions of $x$, one might apply the multivariate chain rule as follows:

$$\frac d{dx}\int_0^uf(y)(v-y)^sdy=u'f(u)(v-u)^s+sv'\int_0^uf(y)(v-y)^{s-1}dy$$

whenever $0<s<1$, $u(x)=v(x)=x$, we end up with

$$\frac d{dx}\int_0^xf(y)(x-y)^sdy=s\int_0^xf(y)(x-y)^{s-1}dy$$

This result means that

$$\frac1{\Gamma(1-s)}\frac d{dx}\int_0^xf(y)(x-y)^{-s}dy=\frac1{\Gamma(2-s)}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\int_0^xf(y)(x-y)^{1-s}dy$$

Now letting $s\to1$ on the RHS gives us

> $$\lim_{s\to1}\frac1{\Gamma(2-s)}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\int_0^xf(y)(x-y)^{1-s}dy=\frac1{\Gamma(1)}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\int_0^xf(y)dy=f'(x)$$

You may also want to check the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Liouville_integral) or Google for other references.

Comment: This is the problem I am thinking. I know it does not exist for $s=1$ so I am asking what would happen for $s\nearrow 1$. Hence, do you have more reference for your second equation? Your last equation is the case $s\searrow1$ which is the case for me that $s=0$.

Comment: @spatially How about now?

Comment: I see. What you are saying is, if $f(y)$ does have $1+s$ order derivative, $0<s<1$, then to compute $s\nearrow 1$, we may compute $1+s\searrow 1$ instead, and this can be done by the yellow block you provided.

Comment: @spatially Yeah, this is more or less how one takes the Riemann-Liouville derivative for values it does not exist.  The more general statement is that$$\frac1{\Gamma(n-s)}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\int_0^xf(y)(x-y)^{n-1-s}dy=\frac1{\Gamma(k-s)}\frac{d^k}{dx^k}\int_0^xf(y)(x-y)^{k-1-s}dy$$for all $n,k$.  Just choose $n,k$ to fit the scenario.